# What is a python function that will determine if the blue intensity of a pixel is greater than or equal to 128

Tags: python

I was wandering what function in python would let me determine if the blue intensity of every pixel in a picture is greater than or equal to 128? Also, what would I need to type in to set a pixel to half of its value if it is greater than 128?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the pixels are stored. But let's just make something up: let's say pixels are tuples of (red, green, blue) values, and your image is a list of rows, each of which is a list of pixels.

First, to check whether a single pixel is blue:

```
pixel[2] >= 128
```

Next, to apply that to every pixel in a row:

```
all(pixel[2] >= 128 for pixel in row)
```

And finally, to apply it to every pixel in every row in an image:

```
all(pixel[2] >= 128 for row in image for pixel in row)
```

To set each pixel to half its value (all three intensities, I'm guessing?) if its blue is `>= 128`, you want to actually use an explicit `for` statement, not a comprehension:

```
for row in image:
    for i, pixel in enumerate(row):
        if pixel[2] > 128:
            row[i] = (pixel[0]//2, pixel[1]//2, pixel[2]//2)
```

Of course if your pixels are stored in a NumPy array, you'll want to use an element-wise comparison instead of a loop. But for any kind of native Python collection, it's going to be a loop something like the one above.